# Jquery: Different click and enter handlers

Tags: jquery, html, button, jquery-click-event

There is a button. I want to detect whether the user has clicked on it or he pressed enter, and do something corresponding to which event occurred. However, when I press enter, both the click and the enter handlers are ecexuted.

How can I solve this problem?

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button">
  Click me
</button>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$("button").keydown(function(e){
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(keyCode === 13){
      $("button").after("<div> enter was pressed </div>");
    }
})

$("button").click(function(){
    $("button").after("<div> click event </div>");
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75wbo7d2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75wbo7d2/4/)**

Use `keyPress` instead :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(keyCode === 13){
    $("button").after("<div> enter was pressed </div>");
  }
});

$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).blur().after("<div> click event </div>");
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(keyCode === 13){
    $("button").after("<div> enter was pressed </div>");
  }
});

$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).blur().after("<div> click event </div>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">
  Click me
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This works fine, except the first time that someone presses enter.

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could helps, for the first time you've just to focus on the document because the event attached to `document`, so just click anywhere inside page then click enter.

Answer (score 1):

Look https://jsfiddle.net/75wbo7d2/3/
with a `e.preventDefault();` you can do it.
Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read somewhere that using preventDefault() is not a very good option because I may cause problems. Is that right?